# reading partitioned datasets stored as csv with pyarrow.dataset

Tags: csv, pyarrow, data-partitioning, apache-arrow

Is there a way in pyarrow how to read in partitioned dataset comprising of csv files that do not have column names stored on the first row?

What i am trying to do is essentially:

```
from pyarrow import dataset as ds
from pyarrow import fs
filesystem = fs.HadoopFileSystem(host = 'my_host', port = 0, kerb_ticket = 'path_to_ticket_cache')
dataset = ds.dataset('path_to_my_dataset',filesystem = filesystem, format = 'csv', partitioning = 'hive')
my_data = dataset.to_table().to_pandas()
```

However, pyarrow by default assumes that each of the CSV files would have the same header, and therefore only correctly loads only the partitioning columns. For the other columns, it thinks that the column names do not match and therefore only data loaded from the first csv file has non-null values in the columns that are not partitioning columns.

is there some workaround how to load the data without headers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in arrow to open individual csv files that don't have headers:

```
table = pa.csv.read_csv(csv_file, pa.csv.ReadOptions(column_names=['col1', 'col2']))
```

with:

```
foo,bar
hello,world
```

It returns:

```
|    | col1   | col2   |
|---:|:-------|:-------|
|  0 | foo    | bar    |
|  1 | hello  | world  |
```

Unfortunately there is no way to pass `pa.csv.ReadOptions` to the `dataset` function.

PS: I think it should be added to `pa.dataset.CsvFileFormat`, there is a ticket for it: https://www.mail-archive.com/jira@arrow.apache.org/msg12849.html

Comment: That's what I am trying to use now, but it gets a bit tedious when you loop over dataset fragments, read table and filter for each file separately.

Answer (score 1):

By default, pyarrow takes the schema inferred from the first CSV file, and uses that inferred schema for the full dataset (so it will project all other files in the partitioned dataset to this schema, and eg losing any columns not present in the first file).

If your files have varying schema's, you can pass a schema manually (to override inferring it from the first file):

```py
schema = pa.schema(...)
dataset = ds.dataset(
    'path_to_my_dataset', filesystem=filesystem, format='csv',
    partitioning='hive', schema=schema,
)
```

See the `schema` argument in https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.dataset.html

However, the above only works if you actually have column names included in the CSV files (to match the correct columns in the file with the schema fields).
If that is not the case, and you want to specify column names manually (instead of using the first row), that will be possible in the future by giving an option to the CSV file format:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from pyarrow import csv

dataset = ds.dataset(
    'path_to_my_dataset', filesystem=filesystem, partitioning='hive', 
    format=ds.CsvFileFormat(read_options=csv.ReadOptions(column_names=["a", "b"]))
)
```

But this keyword is only present starting from pyarrow version 4.0.0 (to be released in April 2021).

Comment: Is it possible to somehow infer data types from the file but column names to provide manually?

Comment: Also, when I provide the schema manually i then see all my non-partitioning columns to have missing values.

Comment: Ah, yes, my answer only works if the names are actually present. What you want (specifying the column names manually if they are not present on the first row of the CSV files) will be possible starting with the next pyarrow 4.0 release (expected in Aprll 2021), see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-8631

Comment: @joris is passing of read and parse options supported at all? when passing `read_options` to `format=CsvFileFormat()` in `ds.dataset()` I get an unexpected keyword argument `read_options` ... I am using pyarrow 7.0.0